# Use XIBs and Storyboards on Nativescript iOS apps

Tags: uistoryboard, xib, nativescript

On native iOS is possibile to load programmatically UIViews from XIBs with the `loadNibNamed` method.

As Nativescript provides a 1-to-1 mapping with iOS APIs, I am wondering if there are techniques to load XIBs (or even ViewController from Storyboards) in a NativeScript iOS only project.

And just for curiosity if for NS Android apps, we can do the same with .XML layout (I am not an Android dev, so I am not sure you can load XML programmatically even natively).

The idea would be to draw User Interfaces with Xcode Interface Builder (or even with Android Studio) and write the business logic in JS/TS.

Answer (score 0):

You ca refer to [this discussion](https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/issues/219) about supporting Storyboards with JS in NativeScript/

Also, demo app created with storyboard can be found at the following link:

https://github.com/NativeScript/ios-runtime/tree/master/examples/Gameraww